# Base Table or View not found Table 'tenancy.websites' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

After I installed hyn multi-tenant package and I run `php artisan tenancy:migrate` I get the error "base table not found." The command is supposed to migrate three migrations. The first being `2017_01_01_000003_tenancy_websites.php`. Here is the content...

```
<?php

class TenancyWebsites extends AbstractMigration
{
    protected $system = true;

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('websites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('uuid');

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('websites');
    }
}
```

Then `2017_01_01_000005_tenancy_hostnames.php`. Here is the content...

```
<?php

class TenancyHostnames extends AbstractMigration
{
    protected $system = true;

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hostnames', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('fqdn')->unique();
            $table->string('redirect_to')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('force_https')->default(false);
            $table->timestamp('under_maintenance_since')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('website_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->foreign('website_id')->references('id')->on('websites')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('hostnames');
    }
}
```

Then `2017_01_01_000003_tenancy_hostnames.php`. Here is the content...

```
class TenancyWebsitesNeedsDbHost extends AbstractMigration
{
    protected $system = true;

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('websites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('managed_by_database_connection')
                ->nullable()
                ->comment('References the database connection key in your database.php');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('websites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('managed_by_database_connection');
        });
    }
}
```

I followed all the steps in their documentation. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Where'd you pull `php artisan tenancy:migrate` from?  The readme doesn't mention that.

Comment: can you show your database migration table

Comment: @Devon from the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code ... are filenames which are not sorted correctly.
**the order of execution is based on the file name**
this is your order

1. 2017_01_01_000003_tenancy_hostnames.php
2. 2017_01_01_000003_tenancy_websites.php
3. 2017_01_01_000005_tenancy_hostnames.php

correct order should be (named with the same class name contained)

1. 2017_01_01_000003_TenancyWebsites.php
2. 2017_01_01_000005_TenancyHostnames.php
3. 2017_01_01_000007_TenancyWebsitesNeedsDbHost.php

Comment: i have rearranged them like you said and i still get the same error.